# Create a List of any type of object based on List of HashMap from JSON

Tags: java, functional-programming, reflection

I have this method that is working as i want:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertDados(Class<T> entity, List<HashMap<String, String>> dados) throws NoSuchMethodException, 
    SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Field[] fields = entity.getDeclaredFields();
        Method[] allSetterMethods = entity.getMethods();
        Map<Integer, Method> setters = new HashMap<>();
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[fields.length -1];
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int cont = 0;
        //AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        T obj = null;

        /*Arrays.stream(allSetterMethods).filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("set")).forEach(m -> {
            int c = 0;

            if(counter.get() > c)
                c = counter.get();

            paramTypes[c] = m.getParameterTypes()[0];
            setters.put(c, m);

            counter.getAndIncrement();
        });*/

        //Pega todos os setter
        for(Method method : allSetterMethods) {         
            if(method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                paramTypes[cont] = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
                setters.put(cont, method);
                cont++;
            }
        }

        for(Map<String, String> map : dados) {
            if(obj == null)
                obj = entity.getConstructor().newInstance();

            for (Field field : fields) {
                if(field.getName().startsWith("serial")) continue;
                for(Map.Entry<Integer, Method> set : setters.entrySet()) {
                    if(set.getValue().getName().substring(3).equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName())) {
                        Integer var = null;

                        if(paramTypes[set.getKey()].equals(Integer.class))
                            var = Integer.parseInt(map.get(field.getName()));

                        Method method = entity.getMethod(set.getValue().getName(), paramTypes[set.getKey()]);
                        method.invoke(obj, var == null ? map.get(field.getName()) : var);
                    }
                }
            }

            result.add(obj);
            obj = null;
        }

        return (List<T>) result;
    }
```

It creates a List of any type of object based on List of HashMap from a json. I'm trying to make it functional and more concise. So i started to change it and so far I have the following modifications:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertDados(Class<T> entity, List<HashMap<String, String>> dados) throws NoSuchMethodException, 
    SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Field[] fields = entity.getDeclaredFields();
        Method[] allSetters = Arrays.stream(entity.getMethods()).filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("set")).toArray(Method[]::new);
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        T obj = null;

        for(Map<String, String> map : dados) {
            if(obj == null)
                obj = entity.getConstructor().newInstance();

            for (Field field : fields) {
                if(field.getName().startsWith("serial")) continue;
                for(Method m : allSetters) {
                    if(m.getName().substring(3).equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName())) {
                        Integer var = null;

                        if(m.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(Integer.class))
                            var = Integer.parseInt(map.get(field.getName()));

                        Method method = entity.getMethod(m.getName(), m.getParameterTypes()[0]);
                        method.invoke(obj, var == null ? map.get(field.getName()) : var);
                    }
                }
            }

            result.add(obj);
            obj = null;
        }

        return (List<T>) result;
    }
```

What is the best way to get rid off the fors taking a functional approach?

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of possible ways:

```
  public static <T> List<T> convertDados(Class<T> entity, List<HashMap<String, String>> dados) {

    final Field[] fields = entity.getDeclaredFields();

    final List<Method> allSetters = Arrays.stream(entity.getMethods())
        .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("set"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return dados.stream()
        .map(map -> {
          try {
            final T obj = entity.getConstructor().newInstance();
            Arrays.stream(fields)
                .map(Field::getName)
                .filter(name -> !name.startsWith("serial"))
                .forEach(fieldName -> {
                  allSetters.stream()
                      .filter(setter -> setter.getName().substring(3).equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName))
                      .forEach(setter -> {
                        final Class<?> paramType = setter.getParameterTypes()[0];
                        try {
                          entity.getMethod(setter.getName(), paramType).invoke(obj, parse(paramType, map.get(fieldName)));
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ignore) {
                        }
                      });
                });
            return Optional.of(obj);
          } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ignore) {
            return Optional.<T>empty();
          }
        })
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private static Object parse(Class<?> paramType, String value) {
    return paramType.equals(Integer.class) ? Integer.parseInt(value) : value;
  }
```